# Use stream reader for a string variable

Tags: vb.net, text, streamreader

Is it possible to make the stream reader to read a string variable, or a textbox instead of a text file? If yes, how?

Answer (score 6):

No but you can use the [**`StringReader`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.aspx) class instead.

`StringReader` and `StreamReader` provide the same consumable interface and both inherit from `TextReader`.

Comment: is there any alternative for "EndOfStream" in the StringReader?

Comment: @user2023328 No because it *hasn’t got* a stream (it reads from a *string*, not a stream). But you shouldn’t need this function – just read the contents via the high-level functions `Read`, `ReadLine` and `ReadToEnd`. Low-level stream functions like `EndOfStream` are more relevant for byte streams which this isn’t anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create a new *IO.Stream* from a **String** or **StringBuilder**

```
Dim s As IO.Stream = New IO.MemoryStream(Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(sb.ToString()))
```

Some functions are not happy with just a StringReader.